# Unpoly up-follow not loading contents via XHR

Tags: unpoly

I have a link like so that isn't being loaded via XHR:

```
<a href="/hb/test2/" up-target="#content" rel="nofollow"><button type="button">Action</button></a>
```

How to get this to load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `type="button"` from the button and it will work.